# MobileFirst 7.1 Direct update issue

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

(1). MobileFirst APP will crash or unstable (sometimes) when the following conditions occur :

We used WL.Client.connect API to trigger direct update  at the same time when iOS native code is running (some native process we wrote) .

(2). We found that  different version of timestamp will not trigger direct update. for example:
Our MobileFirst console version is 7.1.0.00-20151107-1647.We deployed wlapp(builded by 7.1.0.00-20151107-1647 Studio) to that console. 
If the mobile client APP version is 7.1.0.00-20151114-1616 then the direct update won't trigger

Should we make sure that MobileFirst server and client version must be the same?

If so, How to deal with old MobileFirst version APP in Apple store or Google Play to connect new version of MobileFirst server and make sure the direct update , notify and remote disable still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Studio build that you're using contains fixes/changes to the underlying native component of MobileFirst, then Direct Update may not work. You can see this when building in Studio - you get a warning stating this.

In such cases you will need to up the environment `version` value in application-descriptor.xml and upload a new .ipa/.apk to the App Store/Google Play.

Comment: Thank you Idan,
Would the remote disable will work if client APP is older version but the server is newer?